# Proving that $f:(-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x \mapsto x/(1-x^2)$ is strictly increasing?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose that $a_1, a_2 \in (-1, 1)$ are such that $a_1 < a_2$. Then either $a_1^2 = a_2^2$ or $a_1^2 < a_2^2$.

In the first case, $1-a_1^2 = 1-a_2^2$ so that $$a_1/(1-a_1^2) < a_2(1-a_2^2) \implies f(a_1) < f(a_2)$$.

In the second case, $1-a_2^2 > 1-a_1^2 \implies 1/(1-a_2^2)<1/(1-a_1^2)$.

I'm stuck with how to introduce $a_1$ and $a_2$ in the numerators. I would like to prove that the function is strictly increasing without using calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong: if $a_1=-\frac12$, and $a_2=\frac13$, then $a_1,a_2\in(-1,1)$, $a_1<a_2$, but $a_1^{\,2}>a_2^{\,2}$.

On the other hand, if $x\in(-1,1)$, then$$f(x)=\frac x{1-x^2}=x+x^3+x^5+x^7+\cdots,$$and therefore $f$ is increasing, since it is the sum of increasing functions.

Or you can say that $\bigl(\forall x\in(-1,1)\bigr):f'(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}>0$ and that therefore $f$ is increasing.

Comment: I doubt that the OP is knowledgeable of series expansion.

Comment: Right. What about derivatives?

Comment: That’s probably better suited to the way the question is asked!

Comment: This answer helps. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

As the map $f$ is odd, it is sufficient to prove that it is strictly increasing on $I=[0,1)$.

And this is clear as $f$ is the product on that interval of the positive strictly increasing maps

$$g(x)=x, \, h(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$ $h$ being stricly increasing as it is the inverse of a positive strictly decreasing map on $I$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$ \frac{x}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{-2(x-1)} + \frac{1}{-2(x+1)} $$
Each of those two terms is easily seen to be increasing on $(-1,1)$.